# Url with two pk augments returning error "Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(<Story: Story 1>, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Sorry if this is basic but I am very new at this.

I'm trying to create a link with two arguments in it, the second argument seems to be working, but the first returns this error:

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(<Story: Story 1>, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['story\\/(?P<work>[0-9]+)\\/post\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.StoryListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('story/<int:pk>/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='story_overview'),
    path('story/<int:work>/post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

This is the template. This displays all of the posts in a story, and the link should take you to another page that shows a single post. The `work` argument is the id of the sotry from the Story table (which is also present in the Post table)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for posts in object_list %}
    <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' work post.pk %}">{{ posts.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{ posts.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

These are my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from . models import Post, Story

class StoryListView(ListView):
    model = Story
    template_name = 'home.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'story_overview.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.work=get_object_or_404(Story, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Post.objects.filter(work_id=self.work)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['work'] = self.work
        return context

class PostDetailView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

I've this:

```
path('story/<int:storyid>/post/<int:postid>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

 <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' storyid=work postid=post.pk %}">{{ posts.title }}</a></h2>
```

But I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'storyid': <Story: Story 1>, 'postid': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['story\\/(?P<storyid>[0-9]+)\\/post\\/(?P<postid>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

I think that the problem lies between my template and URLs but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you want `work.id` in your template

Comment: @HenryM It worked. Thanks.